# CSS3 transition behavior has odd effect with text wrap on floating element

Tags: css, css-float, css-transitions

I am placing a transition on the margin-top of an element, and I have run into an issue where the text does not wrap properly around a floated element. It appears to work just fine around most of it, but on the tail end it will appear above the floated element. It appears to work properly in the latest version of Firefox (mac), but not in Chrome/Safari (mac):

http://dabblet.com/gist/2704263

I was hoping someone might have some insight on why this is happening, and possibly a solution.

[image: example]

(edit)
I have updated the dabblet to properly show the issue.  Please be sure to hover over text. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are seeing. I've tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari and they all look the same to me... On that note, it's really hard to read words that keep moving.

Comment: I have updated the post with an image of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't understand why, but if you position the image (`position: relative;`) the problem goes away.